# Can I use X windows to show the GUI of a remote process?

Tags: xorg, kubuntu, mac

I remember using screen emulators like Hummingbird to remotely display X processes on Windows, by adjusting environment variables like `TERM` and `SCREEN` (or so) and substituting things like vt100 and IP addresses of the form `nnn.nnn.nnn.nnn:0`

Is it possible using Ubuntu, OSX, between each other between virtual machines etc?

Right now I want to display system monitor graphically with real time updates on an Ubuntu box with an ssh session into a Mac OSX 10.7.2 workstation.  I can get snapshots using ps but I want to monitor the machine live as I am trying to debug responsiveness.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

The simplest thing is to run

```
ssh -X user@host gnome-system-monitor
```

or something similar. The `-X` option allow to run graphical applications on the local X server.

To show a full session, with menu, panels, and so, is more difficult. You can try VNC protocol, available by default on Ubuntu through the client `vinagre`, or FreeNX, or XDMCP.